# How to apply internal Bootstrap/CSS Padding?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have bunch of **dynamic** divs that are getting generated, but I dont know how to pad them internally and align them with left and right edges?
 any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Could you show us your code? A minimal code showing your problem would be enough.

Comment: show at least a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
[class*="col-"] {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

[class*="col-"]:first-child {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

[class*="col-"]:last-child {
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```

> You might add a content to wrap it, otherwise you'll have those rules applied to all columns in your layout!

```
.spaced-columns [class*="col-"] {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

So then you can use:

```
<div class="spaced-columns">
  <div class="col-md-4"> your content here</div>
  <div class="col-md-4"> your content here</div>
  <div class="col-md-4"> your content here</div>
</div>
```

So you'll have your spacing as you want :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out bootstrap. Does most of the css for you:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: I am already using bootstrap, I just dont know how to space them out

Comment: did you check out my link?

Comment: Yes, but didnt find anything about spacing between columns

Comment: Well spacing is mainly padding or margin. and you can use alot of things to measure. To have it responsive I recommend having something like precentages for example:

Comment: <div class="box"></div>

Comment: again I would look at: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp there are alot of information out there that answers this

Answer (score 0):

You can put your div within the `<div class="col-md-4">` or you can simply add a class to it like: `<div class="col-md-4 my-class">` and add some padding to it like:

```
.my-class {
   padding: 10px;
}
```

If you chose to add an idder div, you add the padding to the `<div class="col-md-4">` and simply style your inner div.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="my-class">Text</div>
</div>
```

And style it like:

```
.col-md-4 {
   padding: 10px;
}

.my-class {
   background: red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wrap your column boxes in a  you should be alright. If the padding is still off, you can alter the margin of the row, and then you don't need to mess with the individual column divs.

Example

```
.row {margin-left:-15px;margin-right:-15px;}
```